# Pfsense captive portal does not show on mobile phone

Tags: networking, internet, pfsense

My pfsense router are setup like this:

[image]

My laptop are able to receive the captive portal page and able to access internet through my access point but however, it does not work on mobile phone (iPhone). Can someone help?

My setup are quite simple. I set my captive portal using vouchers. I am able to use it on my laptop. But not on my mobile phone.

Comment: This may be related to how Apple devices deal with captive portal pages and the Apple WISPr (where Apple devices attempt to connect to Apple services to confirm connectivity). I don't know whether you might need to whitelist Apple services to allow the captive portal to allow Apple to communicated with (bypass the cpative portal) to allow them to recognise a captive portal is in use?! I don't know the technology

Comment: @Kinnectus it works the first time but there’s no internet connection... after awhile it stops working for phones..

Comment: What Version of pfsense are you using?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart pfsense 2.4.4